# How to resolve type of Object.entries

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have some types defined as following:

```
type SomeData = {
  field1?: string;
  field2?: string;
}

interface User {
  name?: string;
  enabled?: boolean;
  someData?: SomeData;
}

interface InitValue {
  name: (string | undefined)[];
  enabled: (boolean | undefined)[];
  someData: (SomeData | undefined)[];
}
```

and some variables that uses these types:

```
let values: InitValue = {
  name: [],
  enabled: [],
  someData: []
}

const users: User[] = [
  {
    name: 'A',
    enabled: true,
  },
  {
    name: 'B',
    enabled: false,
    someData: {
      field1: 'field1 value'
    }
  }
]
```

I want from `users` to fill my `values` object like following:

```
users.forEach((user)=> {
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(user)) {
    values[key].push(value)
  }
})
```

But this generates me a typescript error:

```
Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'InitValue'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'InitValue'.
```

it's because `Object.entries` didn't return the types of `user`.

If I use a switch statement this will work:

```
users.forEach((user)=> {
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(user)) {
    switch (key) {
      case 'name':
      values[key].push(value)
      break;
      case 'enabled':
      values[key].push(value)
      break;
    }
  }
})
```

but I dont want to use it, since in real data I have there is more than 100 fields and I don't want to repeat that for every single key.

What I want is to resolve the type of `key` and `value`.

How can I solve this?

here is the full TS Playground:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwgEQIbFVAvFA3gWACgooAzASwgBsATARgH4AuKAZ2ACdyA7AcwG4iJCtRoAmZm048BRAL5EiPYBA6lUAY2gBVVqrxCo3VEknsufQcSgRjAIyoQaku3DiPU3KyVaIU6VEl4JDQMKwVCJW4VNU1oAElucmAANVQqAFdoAmtjJBYACnMZKAAfKAzuGggKbicASgBtAF1vG3tHGkLXdwhPMoqqmp4GlrbfEIDC4P8MAcrq2tHW+UVCR2AoADd0rNYWROS0zOgcHJI8iBYWgBpDW1QHJ2vmu+sJ2dQX1cjCDThuOwKnoOPsoLpVC1sFBGoZziQjCYrlAAOQAQRRbwR7UenRYnCyWKgciJ8IuSJYKIAQpjDCQHk8umR0noiT4-KEvgZrNiRLQ6JS+fRtrsICi6cTDBFmmsMiDWAA6UhwDgAUU0AAsCgU5ap6lgAHzc4QqqAFf6AzaNADWEBANxFJ2aUDgpCgAHk7AArCAaYAK2zSCCsHUg+r1Y0InYnVg2u3NBVgOVa6NZepS+Tp3660FKlXqjRa0N6w2R5UcM0WoFx+2OrLO10e72+-2BrjB4sccORnwAd2ShbNtpAEbJCI0qD0qMuKKYEpIqeDNYTSdYKdFWexJDsHD61ra2InU5RDM6s-ndaXw5XyYKi83W53e4PkusETk9SAA

Comment: You could use a type assertion, but TypeScript is right: just knowing that `user` implements the `User` interface does not say anything about extra properties it might have, so `Object.entries` needs to type `key` as `string`, not `keyof User`. Notice that your code will actually break if you add more properties to the objects without initialising an array for them in `values`.

Comment: If you're sure that `user` contains no more than the properties of `User` you can assert, but then if you want the compiler to understand what you're doing after that, you need to refactor to use generics and mapped types as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mMzKrW).  I could write that up as an answer if it fully addresses your question; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: jcalz it looks like you are using some seriously advanced typescript I would greatly appreciate it if you could explain what you are doing with your typings. As I have also struggled with this problem a lot and your solution seems to solve it perfectly!

Comment: I'll consider writing an answer but I'd rather hear back from OP in case it's not what they're looking for.